# building a commandbuilder from a strong typed dataset without writing sql code?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have the following scenario:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
MyConnection = New SqlConnection(sConnect)
MyCommand = New SqlCommand(sSQL, MyConnection)
MyConnection.Open()
MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader
```

What I'd like is to avoid to manually write the sql sentence. I have a strong typed dataset and I'm wondering If I could use it to do it. I've tried using the commandbuilder, but I need the dataadapter for initialize it, and to initialize the dataadapter I have also to write the sql sentence...

The purpose would be, having the strong typed dataset, use it for field-syntax validation.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean like Entity Framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx ) , or another such ORM?

Comment: An ORM is the way to go, as @podiluska suggests. For SQL Server I prefer Entity Framework.

Comment: thank you @podiluska, I didn't know the entity framework! I have worked with other ORMs, like hibernate, but EF is far easiear and integrated into the visual studio, thank you very much!